# How Not To Bash Auto Complete File Name From the Beginning Letter?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

Say I'm in a directory and have a file called `01_test.py` and if there are too many files in the folder and I forget the beginning of the file name and only remember there is a `test` in the file name, then if I try to edit it in Terminal it won't auto complete the file name for me:

```
$ vi test
# it won't autocomplete the file name for me if I hit tab key
```

the reason behind this is that `test` is not at the beginning of the file name, so is there anyway that can let bash autocomplete the file name for me if only provided the middle part of the file name?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

vi *test* ctrl + x (then type * )

You not need leave a space when after *test* when type control + x if not, this not work

```
vi *test*ctrl + x *
```

Comment: but if there are more than one file with `test` in the file name, then here is a modified solution based on your answer: `$ vi *test*` and then hit `tab` until it shows that file name you want to edit.